# Render ByteBuffer into SurfaceView in Android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have an Android USB Camera application which will pump Camera frames to FrameAvaliable() method. The data retrieved from this method is a valid one (Confirmed by saving into raw file as image). I'm trying to render the frames from FrameAvaliable on SurfaceView created.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements USBCameraListener{

SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private Thread rendererThread;
private boolean isStarted;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    isStarted = false;

    surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(final SurfaceHolder holder) {

            surfaceHolderORG   =   holder;

            Log.d(TAG, "Surface Created");

            rendererThread =   new Thread(){

                @Override
                public void run() {


                    while(true) {

                        if (isStarted== true) {
                            //Added code
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[frameBuffer.remaining()];
                            int offset = 0, n = 0;

                            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

                            try {

                                while (offset < bytes.length
                                        && (n = in.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
                                    offset += n;

                                }
                                in.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            // getting byte array
                            Bitmap bmp;
                            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            options.inMutable = true;
                            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, options);
                            Canvas canvas = surfaceHolderORG.lockCanvas();
                            if (canvas != null) {

                                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
                                surfaceHolderORG.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); 

                            }


                        }

                    }

                }

            };



            rendererThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }
    });


    // Frame Listener
    @Override
    public void FrameAvailable(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
            frameBuffer = byteBuffer;

            if(isStarted == false){
               startedProducer =   true;
            }
    }
}

}
```

When frames start to produce from FrameAvailable() , the condition check enters renderer code in rendererThread and the application throws the following exception and nothing is preview in SurfaceView.

```
12-26 03:05:20.590 12023-12104/com.sample.USBAPP D/skia: --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
12-26 03:05:20.590 3613-5139/? E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceView] connect(P): already connected (cur=1 req=2)
12-26 03:05:20.590 12023-12104/com.sample.USBAPP E/SurfaceHolder: Exception locking surface
12-26 03:05:20.590 12023-12104/com.sample.USBAPP E/SurfaceHolder: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
12-26 03:05:20.590 12023-12104/com.sample.USBAPP E/SurfaceHolder:     at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
```

I don't know where i was going wrong.

Comment: The Surface thinks there's already something drawing on it. Is it also being used as a camera preview surface?

Comment: Thank you fadden for your reply. I was using the same surface for both camera preview as well as rendering the USB frames. But I haven't started the Camera preview, this part is untouched (only i have configured camera preview side).

Comment: bmp object returned null after decodeByteArray is called. My FrameAvailable() method is receiving MJPEG frame format data in the form of ByteBuffer. Is decodeByteArray() method not able to decode this data ?